# How to Convert list of string to tuple in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am facing a problem to convert from List to tuple. For example i have lists like this

```
['1', '9']
['2']
['3']
['4']
```

I want output like this
    [(1,9),(2),(3),(4)]
Kindly help me. I am not getting any way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list 'l' then you can call the builtin function 'tuple' on it to convert to a tuple

```
l = [1,2]
tup = tuple(l)
print tup # (1,2)
```

if you have a list of list l = [['1', '9'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]

you can do :

```
l = [['1', '9'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]
tups = map(lambda x: tuple(x), l)
print tups #  [(1,9),(2),(3),(4)]
```

Comment: Thank you  @gypsy. I am new to Python , so could not figure out it.